# Promises or async/await in mongosh?

Tags: mongodb-shell

I have a mongosh script that should execute things synchronously. Can I use promises or async/await in mongosh? It seems like I can't. Is there a way to ensure things don't get executed out of order?

For example

```
(1) db.clients.find({}).forEach((client) => {
  db.addresses.insertMany([
    { ....
    }

(2) db.addresses.find({}).forEach...
```

2 gets executed by the mongosh when 1 is still looping. Any thoughts?

Comment: It could be possible inside a constructor (or property, which is not explicitly mentioned). See [Limitations on Database Calls](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/#limitations-on-database-calls)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two separate scripts, so be sure to finish the first before running the second.

```
mongosh $MONGODB_URI queries/first.js queries/second.js
```